# How do I force timer volume on, regardless of Vibrate or Mute mode in Android 7.0?

Tags: audio, 7.0-nougat, alarm, clock, vibration

I always keep my phone on Vibrate.

That being said, I've never had this issue before until I had to get a new phone on 7.0. Previously, the phone I had from 6.0 through the upgrade to 7 would always make noise with the timer in the default Clock app while set to Vibrate. Now that I have a new phone (same model), it's never made noise with the timer unless my phone's sound is on.

The same questions were asked for [4.4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87755/how-to-have-the-alarm-audible-when-on-vibrate-or-silent) and [5.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130086/how-do-i-set-android-s-clock-app-to-vibrate-for-timers), so this will be the 7.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer possible with the default Clock app in Android 7.0. If you set your phone to vibrate, there is no way to enable notification volume which the timer depends on.

I removed the Clock app shortcuts everywhere on my phone and started using [Alarm Clock Xtreme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free&hl=en) for timers.